# Fullcalendar 2.5 eventSource url appends start and end date incorrectly formatted

Tags: c#, angularjs, fullcalendar, momentjs

So I'm in the process of upgrading fullcalendar from 1x to 2x in an AngularJS application and I'm running into some issues where the eventSource url needed to gather the calendar events is appending the start and end param dates formatted as (YYYY-MM-DD) when it needs to be in seconds--I think--at least that's what we had in version 1x which was working.

When my controller is instantiated the first thing I do is establish the eventSources variable needed to pass into the fullcalendar directive (I'm using the angular fullcalendar wrapper directive: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/).

HTML:

```
<div id="calendar" class="col-sm-9" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar" config="uiConfig.calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.eventSources = [];
for (var i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++) {
    $scope.eventSources[i] = getEventSource(calendars[i]);
}

var getEventSource = function(calendar) {
        return {
            cid: calendar.cal_head_id,
            url: "/api/classroom/student/calendar?ids=" + calendar.cal_head_id,
            className: 'calendar-' + calendar.sort_order,
            backgroundColor: calendar.color_code
        };
    };
```

However my string param keeps coming out as:

```
ids=2525213&start=2015-11-30&end=2016-01-11&_=1449868998385
```

And finally my server side code to handle the request:

```
[ActionName("calendar")]
        public JsonArray GetCalendarEvents(string ids, int start, int end)
        {
            var calendars = ids.Split(',');
            var startDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(start);
            var endDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(end);

            var data = new CalendarService().GetEvents(calendars, 0, startDate, endDate);

            var events = new JsonArray();
            var results = (JsonArray) data["results"];

            foreach (JsonObject obj in results)
            {
                var name = ((JsonString) obj["name"]).Value;
                if (name == "<b>Homework</b>")
                {
                    name = "<img src=/images/icons/house.png /> Homework";
                }

                var link = ((JsonString) obj["link"]).Value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link) && link.Contains("doEditEvent"))
                {
                    link = "";
                }

                var eventStart = Convert.ToDateTime(obj["start_time"].ToString());
                var eventEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(obj["end_time"].ToString());

                events.Add(new JsonObject
                {
                    {"id", obj["event_id"]},
                    {"calId", obj["calendar_id"]},
                    // Note: Firefox requires the dates are in the below format - JD 6/12/2013
                    {"start", eventStart.ToString("o")},
                    {"end", eventEnd.ToString("o")},
                    {"allDay", eventStart == eventEnd.AddMinutes(1).AddDays(-1)},
                    {"title", name},
                    {"link", link},
                    {"description", obj["description"]}
                });
            }

            return events;
        }
```

The problem with manually adding the start and end is that fullcalendar does this by default, so it concatenates the params multiple times. According to the documentation on upgrading from 1x to 2x (http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/) the library was updated to use moment, which is great because I assumed that would fix any formatting issues, and I definitely have that included in my project.

I'm looking for a solution here that's not going to involve me tampering with the fullcalendar source code hopefully, otherwise I'll need to go back to 1x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startParam and endParam changed from v1 to v2, from UNIX timestamp to ISO8601 style date string. You will have to either add additional parameters containing timestamp, hack fullcalendar.js to send timestamp, rework your server side code, or use v1.xx

For your server side code, seems like you could change it to

```
[ActionName("calendar")]
        public JsonArray GetCalendarEvents(string ids, string start, string end)
        {
            var calendars = ids.Split(',');
            var startDate = DateTime.parse(start);
            var endDate = DateTime.parse(end);
```

If you want to override the 'start' and 'end' to be UNIX stamps this could work.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spefy4px/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  /* You can rename the start and end params from 'start' and 'end' */
  /* In this code, 'start', 'end' and 'startDate' and 'endDate' will be on URL */
  startParam: 'startDate',
  endParam: 'endDate',
  eventSources: [{
    url: '/test', /* Set this to whatever is appropriate */
    data: function() {
        var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
      return {
        /* Then you can change 'start' and 'end' in the URL to be UNIX stamps */
        'start': view.start.unix(),
        'end': view.end.unix(),
      };
    },
    /* This is just to demo the URL being queried, not required */
    beforeSend: function () {
        alert(this.url);
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: Changing the server side code did it for me and will be the solution I go with, though it could be nice to learn how to do it manually. The issue I was having when I tried that manual approach was that I didn't know how I would stop fullcalendar from appending those params a second time.

Comment: I added some code that will rename the start/end parameters and override them to UNIX timestamps.